# How do you move a just the date with spaces, time and AM/PM in Excel/CSV with a formula?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have a date in an excel/csv document that was exported from an old ASP app that I am going to import into Wordpress/MySQL and I just need to display the date.  Each cell has a date like this:

2/22/2006  6:27:55 AM

I just want

2/22/2006

I am moving the date from 1 sheet to another by looking up an ID number and all the other data I was able to move with formulas no problem (=VLOOKUP(G2,Firm!$A$2:$P$1392,4,0)

when I move the date it turns it into 38770.76938

I was going to try to remove the ( 6:27:55 AM) but this formula wasn't working either: =LEFT(P2,FIND(" ",P2&" ")-1)

Can anyone help?  There are about 5,000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

@greg-you can format column using custom modification.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link contains details: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Use this formula
    =MONTH(A2) & "/" & DAY(A2) & "/" & YEAR(A2)